# Why is dissatisfactorily not a word?

Tags: word-usage

Unsatisfactory, unsatisfactorily, and dissatisfactory are real words, but why is dissatisfactorily not a real word?

I understand the difference between the two forms (un- vs dis-): [What's the difference between "dissatisfied" and "unsatisfied"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165153/whats-the-difference-between-dissatisfied-and-unsatisfied)

In constructing this sentence:

> Dissatisfied employees work dissatisfactorily

I was disappointed to learn that *dissatisfactorily* is not in any online dictionary I consulted.

I know I could say:

> unsatisfied employees work unsatisfactorily

but I think that changes the meaning significantly. *Unsatisfied* is almost passive and invokes thoughts of disappointment, while *dissatisfied* describes disapproval. So it makes sense to me that since one has an adverb so would the other. Is there something about the word *dissatisfactorily* that it fails to make logical sense? Is there some other reason why it is not a word?

---

[A similar question comes close](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/is-dissatisfactorily-the-correct-adverb-for-not-satisfying), but the OP is clearly looking for *unsatisfactorily* to describe what is felt in the given situation.

Comment: _Unsatisfactorily_ inherently carries the notion of disapproval (by the person applying the term): the work is unsatisfactory, the assessor dissatisfied. There isn't a parallel with the pair _dissatisfied_ and _unsatisfied_, where one or the other may apply.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's not the impression I get from the use I observe and from this post: [What's the difference between "dissatisfied" and "unsatisfied"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/165193) The work can be both un- and dis- and the assessor the corresponding word.

Comment: Are you saying that an assessor won't necessarily be dissatisfied with unsatisfactory work? I'd say they're bound to be.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In a way, yes. His demands were unsatisfied, as in, not fully met. If the work was dissatisfactory then the assessor's demands that the work be done would be satisfied, but to his dissatisfaction, it would be done by a standard less then his own.

Comment: So I would say that the assessor can be dissatisfied that his demands were were unsatisfied, as in not met.

Comment: I'm saying that the assessor must be dissatisfied with unsatisfactory work, so dissatisfactorily (in a manner bound to cause dissatisfaction?) would be an unneeded synonym of unsatisfactorily (not producing acceptable results) as someone has to pronounce on unacceptability. Either the assessor is satisfied or they're not. There is no objective 'pass / fail' criterion, as someone has to decide on what that criterion is.

Answer (score 1):

Because a word is not in any dictionary does not invalidate its use in formal register. Particularly this will apply to a regular grammatical inflection of an infrequently used word.

You will be comforted to know that whilst it does not mention ***dissatisfactorily***, the OED (which is as ultimate an authority on the English language as you will find) does include both ***dissatisfactoriness*** and ***dissatisfying*** as derivatives.

Thus, if I were you, I would have no concerns about using ***dissatisfactorily***.

Comment: This is good news. By "formal register" do you mean formal writing and such?

Comment: though, I would probably use dissatisfyingly.

Comment: @AverageGatsby Not a bad alternative. What is the nuanced difference between *dissatisfyingly* and *dissatisfactorily*?

Comment: I certainly would have concerns. Senses sometimes switch markedly even between intercategorial polysemes (a phone, to phone; but a telescope; to telescope), never mind slightly less close relatives (a scheming individual, a scheme of work). And inflections are not guaranteed to work identically (escapee is one who has escaped). So how can are you supposed to understand a string not even generally accepted as a word?

Comment: @fredsbend I expressed myself badly. I can't precisely grasp the reason why, but I would use dissatisfyingly to describe actions and dissatisfactorily if at all to modify adjectives. "This is a dissatisfactorily arbitrary answer", I know.

Comment: @AverageGatsby The more I think about it the more I think your alternative is more appropriate. Dissatisfaction is a feeling while dissatisfy is an action. In my example, I'm describing work, not alluding to feelings. I think we're on the same thought process here.

Comment: @AverageGatsby In that particular example wouldn't *unsatisfactorily* apply? *The council staff went about the job of cleaning dog excrement from the park dissatisfactorily*.

Comment: @fredsbend In my above example concerning the council staff, *dissatisfyingly* does not sound right to me. It suggests that it would be a job that normally brought satisfaction. *Dissatisfacorily* seems to emphasise their discontent, which is how I interpret the word *dissatisfy*.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, I agree, but in a way, it implies that they've been put to the task against their satisfaction (they'd rather not do it).